# Matlab - Segment cell nucleus from similar background

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment the nucleus of the cell in an image so I can extract its boundary. The nucleus and the background of the image are very similar so I am finding it difficult to do this using the something like erosion.

If anyone could suggest a way to remove the background and keep the nucleus that would be very helpful.

Image:

[image: cell nucleus]

Comment: Yes it is it's about segmentation methods

Comment: It's just the red central region I am trying to extract, but when converted to black and white, it doesn't work so well as the background is the same colour as it.

Comment: Have you looked at working on just the red channel?

Comment: @Dan I'm new to this, how exactly would I go about that.

Comment: If your image is a standard 3D matrix (such as that given by `imread`), then just extract the first channel like this: `I_red = I(:,:,1)`.

Comment: RGB's approach is fast and can provide a quick fix, but there might be red in other parts of the image. Converting to HSV is an option, or YCbCr as suggested by @Shai

Comment: Is it a real nucleus? or a graphic representation? Never seen before. It looks good.

Answer (score 6):

You need to work with different color space. Try [`YCbCr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) for instance

```
oimg = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYhrS.png');
img = rgb2ycbcr(oimg); % conver RGB to YCbCr color space
msk = img(:,:,3)>130;  % apply threshold on Cr channel to get segmentation mask
```

I picked up 130 as arbitrary threshold, you might need to adjust it a bit.
Showing the input image, the image region for which `msk==1`, and the background:
[image]

I'll leave it to you as an exercise to think why the `Cr` channel performed well for this image.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're running into difficulty is because you're doing a black-white conversion, and this step is "throwing out" your best differentiating feature. Try doing the segmentation in a non b-w color space. The segmentation itself can be done pretty easily using k-means clustering:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYhrS.png');
imshow(img)

cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_he = applycform(img,cform);

% classify the colors in 'a*b*' Space Using k-means clustering
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

% Looks like there are ~3 colors in the image
nColors = 3;

% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
                                  'Replicates',3);

pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);

% nucleus is in the center. figure out what its label is.
middleX = round(size(img,2)/2);
middleY = round(size(img,1)/2);

nucleusLabel = pixel_labels(middleX,middleY);

figure
tempImg = bsxfun(@eq,pixel_labels,nucleusLabel);
tempImg = bsxfun(@times,double(tempImg),double(img));

imshowpair(img,tempImg/max(tempImg2(:)),'montage')
```

[image]

Comment: you can `reshape` without explicitly computing the number of points: `ab=reshape( ab, [], 2 );`

Comment: you should use `bsxfun` to get `tempImg` from the mask `pixel_labels ~= nucleusLabel` instead of loop over the channels.

Comment: have you tried mean-shift segmentation? should preserve the spatial relations between the pixels...

Comment: Good point! Replaced the loop with `bsxfun`. Haven't tried mean-shift segmentation yet, though.